# Restart of nginx service fails because of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failure

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

Installing 3rd party SSL on DigitalOcean Droplet, Apache running Ubuntu 12.10.

Following the instructions here:

- [AlphaSSL on Apache](http://www.alphassl.com/support/create-csr/apache.html)
- [Self signed SSL instructions from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04)

So everything seems to be going all right. I make the edits to all the appropriate files according to the tutorials above, I put in the certificate information I got from AlphaSSL, but when I try to reboot `nginx` is where I'm hitting a snag.

```
root@omitted:/etc/nginx/sites-available# sudo service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file("/etc/nginx/cert.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Googling this error led me to the following [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/537343/nginx-startup-fails-ssl-no-such-file-or-directory) page, where the fix was to change directory permissions with the following, which I did:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
sudo chown -R root:root /etc/nginx/ssl
sudo chmod -R 600 /etc/nginx/ssl
```

but I'm still getting the error. I think I'm missing something. Help.

**Edit** I just realised the cert.pem file does not exist, but I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` : (superlong but I didn't know what to leave out...)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: Are you sure `/etc/nginx/cert.pem` is there?

Comment: Crickey - you're right it's not there. I'm not sure how to create it either.

Comment: Try and post your nginx.conf so we can see

Comment: Remove the last comment to have the closing `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error, it seems like `nginx` can't find `/etc/nginx/cert.pem` file, I'd suggest you to double check path and permissions (switch to nginx's user and try reading this file).

Answer (score 0):

Just check if /etc/nginx/cert.pem is existing. And make sure that certification file is valid. Or you should re-generate a new one.